# Laravel Elequent relationhips

Tags: php, laravel-5.5, eloquent, laravel-query-builder

I am pulling my hair out here, I have to almost identical elequent queries. They should be bringing back similar results, but they are not.

Take note of the **ReportsData** in both controllers and the difference in the output, specifically the **reports_data":[]** relationships. the first example it outputs as expected, the second does not grab anything.

I hope someone can shed some light on this, I have been pulling my hair out for hours now :(

Here is my code

**Controller**

```
    $report = ReportsSuspect::where('id', '=', $id)
            ->with('serverModel')
            ->with('reportsReportModel')
            ->with('reportsReporter')
            ->with('reportsData')
            ->get();
    $reports = ReportsReport::where('suspect_id', '=', $id)
            ->with('serverModel')
            ->with('reportsSuspect')
            ->with('reportsReporter')
            ->with('reportsData')
            ->get();
```

**$Report outputs the following**

```
[{"id":4,"steamid":"0987654321","assigned":0,"archived":0,"created_at":"2017-11-30 14:03:45","updated_at":"2017-11-30 14:03:45","server_model":null,"reports_report_model":[{"id":9,"name":"hackerName","offence":"Hacking-ESP\/AIM, Toxic Behaviour","server":25,"suspect_id":4,"reporter_id":3,"created_at":"2017-11-30 14:03:45","updated_at":"2017-11-30 14:03:45"}],"reports_reporter":null,"reports_data":[{"id":16,"reporter_id":3,"suspect_id":4,"moderator_id":0,"comment":null,"url":"image1","comment_type":0,"url_type":1,"created_at":"2017-11-30 14:03:45","updated_at":"2017-11-30 14:03:45"},{"id":17,"reporter_id":3,"suspect_id":4,"moderator_id":0,"comment":null,"url":"video1","comment_type":0,"url_type":2,"created_at":"2017-11-30 14:03:45","updated_at":"2017-11-30 14:03:45"},{"id":18,"reporter_id":3,"suspect_id":4,"moderator_id":0,"comment":"I saw this guy hacking","url":null,"comment_type":1,"url_type":0,"created_at":"2017-11-30 14:03:45","updated_at":"2017-11-30 14:03:45"}]}]
```

**$reports Outputs the follwoing**

```
[{"id":9,"name":"hackerName","offence":"Hacking-ESP\/AIM, Toxic Behaviour","server":25,"suspect_id":4,"reporter_id":3,"created_at":"2017-11-30 14:03:45","updated_at":"2017-11-30 14:03:45","server_model":{"id":25,"servername":"Rustafied Long","serverlocation":"US","available":1,"servertextname":"US - Long","servertype":1,"serverconnection":"","serverinfo":"","serverpopulation":"","created_at":null,"updated_at":null},"reports_suspect":{"id":4,"steamid":"0987654321","assigned":0,"archived":0,"created_at":"2017-11-30 14:03:45","updated_at":"2017-11-30 14:03:45"},"reports_reporter":{"id":3,"steamid":"76561198363172919","name":"Cake","created_at":"2017-11-30 09:21:40","updated_at":"2017-11-30 09:21:40"},"reports_data":[]}]
```

**ReportsSuspectController**

```
 //  Relationship data
public function reportsReport(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\reportsReport', 'reporter_id');
}
public function reportsData(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\reportsData', 'suspect_id');
}
public function reportsReportModel(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\reportsReport', 'suspect_id');
}
public function reportsReporter(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\reportsReporter', 'id');
}
public function serverModel(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\server', 'server');
}
```

**ReportsReportController**

```
//  Relationship data
public function reportsSuspect(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\reportsSuspect', 'suspect_id');
}
public function reportsReporter(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\reportsReporter', 'reporter_id');
}
public function ReportsData(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\reportsData', 'suspect_id');
}
public function serverModel(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Server', 'server');
}
public function offenceModel(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Offence', 'offence');
}
```

**reports_data table**

```
id      int(10)             No  None
reporter_id     int(11)             Yes     NULL
suspect_id  int(11)             Yes     NULL    
moderator_id    int(11)             No  0   
comment text    utf8_unicode_ci         Yes     NULL 
url     text    utf8_unicode_ci         Yes     NULL 
comment_type    int(11)             Yes     0 
url_type    int(11)             Yes     0 
created_at  timestamp           Yes     NULL 
updated_at  timestamp           Yes     NULL
```

**reports_report table**

```
id  i   nt(10)              No  None    
name    text    utf8_unicode_ci         Yes     NULL
offence text    utf8_unicode_ci         Yes     NULL
server  int(11)                 Yes     NULL
suspect_id  int(11)             Yes     NULL
reporter_id     int(11)             Yes     NULL
created_at  timestamp           Yes     NULL
updated_at  timestamp           Yes     NULL
```

**reports_suspect table**

```
idPrimary   int(10)             No  None    
steamid     varchar(25)     utf8_unicode_ci Yes     NULL
assigned    int(11)             Yes     0
archived    int(11)             No  0
created_at  timestamp           Yes     NULL
updated_at  timestamp           Yes     NULL
```

Comment: I guess the problem is from the naming. 

`public function ReportsData()` should be `reportsData` and  `with('ReportsData')` should be `with('reportsData')` as well for `ReportsReporter` 

https://github.com/alexeymezenin/laravel-best-practices#follow-laravel-naming-conventions

Comment: I almost kicked myself, But that did not fix the issue. I shall update the code above to reflect that

Comment: Your foreign keys seems wrong. Can we see your database schema?

Comment: Updated - I have referenced $table = ''; in the model also

Answer (score 0):

FIXED!!

**ReportsRepor** required the foreign_key other_key

```
public function ReportsData(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\reportsData', 'suspect_id', 'suspect_id');
}
```